# Laravel store to wrong path

Tags: laravel

I have added my project to the server for production. i moved everything in the public folder outside to public_html. i have changed the index. php and removed the .. before bootstrap. the site is working fine but the problem now is when i upload any picture laravel creates folder called uploads in public and upload the pictures there and i can't view the pictures until i move it to the upload folder outside public which it supposse to upload there from the beginning.

anyone know how to change the upload path please???

Comment: add codes please

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you AppServiceProvider

```
if(env('APP_ENV') == "production"){
   $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
       return base_path() . '/../public_html';
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but nothing works. still upload it to the public folder. also when i open filesystem.php in the config folder. i found these code

Answer (score 0):

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'gad'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'gad' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/uploads',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/uploads/',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

];

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image anywhere you like,
 eg :

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$request->file('photo')->move($destionation_path, file_name_you_give);
```